# nestjs mongoose self referenced sub document model type error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

i have a nestjs backend with mongoose running. when i modeled my DB in paper, i needed a section with relation to it self to represent subsections (something like category and sub category). i did this code in my model:

```js
@Schema()
export class Section {
  @Prop()
  title: string;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed })
  context: SurveyDocument | ListDocument;

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Section' }] })
  subSections: SectionDocument[];

  // for sub sections
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Section' })
  parentSection: SectionDocument;
}

export type SectionDocument = Section & mongoose.Document;

export const SectionSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Section);
```

and this on my service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SectionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Section.name)
    private readonly sectionModel: Model<SectionDocument>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<SectionDocument[]> {
    return this.sectionModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

but the `Model<SectionDocument>` will give me this error:

```
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type 'LeanDocument<SectionDocument>'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type 'Omit<_LeanDocument<SectionDocument>, "populate" | "$ignore" | "$isDefault" | "$isDeleted" | "$isEmpty" | "$isValid" | "$locals" | "$markValid" | ... 43 more ... | "$isSingleNested">'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<SectionDocument>>'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '_LeanDocument<SectionDocument>'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: "_id"; __v?: "__v"; id?: "id"; title: "title"; context: "context"; subSections: "subSections"; parentSection: "parentSection"; }'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: "_id"; __v?: "__v"; id?: "id"; title: "title"; context: "context"; subSections: never; parentSection: "parentSection"; }'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: "_id"; __v?: "__v"; id?: "id"; title: never; context: never; subSections: never; parentSection: "parentSection"; }'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: "_id"; __v?: never; id?: "id"; title: "title"; context: "context"; subSections: "subSections"; parentSection: "parentSection"; }'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: "_id"; __v?: never; id?: "id"; title: never; context: never; subSections: "subSections"; parentSection: "parentSection"; }'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: "_id"; __v?: never; id?: "id"; title: never; context: never; subSections: never; parentSection: "parentSection"; }'.ts(2615)
Type of property 'parentSection' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ _id?: never; __v?: never; id?: never; title: never; context: never; subSections: never; parentSection: never; }'.ts(2615)
```

and i wonder is there something that i am doing wrong or it is just a typescript error?